# How to parallelize a process in a subclass in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, multiprocess

I am working on a project, where I have a main function, a class called `simulator` and a class called `vehicle`. In the main function I call: `simulator.run()` which calls `vehicle.run()` for all vehicles in `simulator.vehicle_list[]`.

The vehicles have to calculate a trajectory, which is time-consuming process. These processes are independent of each other and I want the `vehicle.run()` calculations to run on multiple CPU cores.

As starter I have created a simple project (with different class-names, than above, but intuitive enough I hope) but I cannot get it to work.
My code doesn't call `self.calculate()` in the subclass. When I remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement from the master class, I get the error:

```
'multi_subclass' object has no attribute '_closed'
```

The three python files I have:

multi_main.py

```
from multi_class import multi_class

main_class = multi_class()
main_class.calculate()

#main_class.calculate2()
```

multi_class.py

```
from multi_subclass import multi_subclass

class multi_class():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am multi_class")
        subclass_list = []
        for i in range(10):
            subclass_list += [multi_subclass()]
        self.subclass_list = subclass_list
        
    def calculate(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            processes = []
            for i in range(10):
                processes.append(self.subclass_list[i])
                self.subclass_list[i].start()
                
            [proc.join() for proc in processes]
```

multi_subclass.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class multi_subclass(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am multi_subclass")
        
    def calculate(self):
        print("Running massive calculations")
        self.member_variable = "Finished with calculation"
        
    def calculate2(self):
        print("I also want to be paralellized but NOT together with calculate!")
        
    def run(self):
        self.calculate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this statement `if __name__ == '__main__':` is put in place so that if the main process spawns up new processes, those new processes won't spawn new processes as well.

So, your entry point should have that.

**multi_main.py**

```
from multi_class import multi_class
from timeit import default_timer


start = default_timer()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main_class = multi_class()
    main_class.calculate()
    print(f"Your code ran in {default_timer() - start} seconds instead of 10 seconds because of multiprocessing.LOL")
```

**multi_class.py** <-- Class responsible for spinning up new processes.
There were a couple of issues in the `calculate()` function.

```
from multi_subclass import multi_subclass

class multi_class():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am multi_class")
        subclass_list = []
        for i in range(10):
            subclass_list += [multi_subclass()]
        self.subclass_list = subclass_list

    def calculate(self):
        processes = []

        for i in range(10):
            # you were putting a different process in the list and never starting it but you were waiting for it to complete using `.join()` and starting a different process but never waiting for it to complete
            # fixed code below
            # processes.append(self.subclass_list[i])
            # self.subclass_list[i].start() 
            

            # create a process, put it in the list, start it
            process = self.subclass_list[i]
            processes.append(process)
            process.start()

        # wait for it to complete here
        [proc.join() for proc in processes]
```

**multi_subclass.py** < -- Most important class and I liked the idea of you inheriting the Process class, so now your class is also a Process class. Cool

But the problem was, when you create a `Process()` using `multiprocessing` module, you provide a target to run when the process starts like this -> `Process(target=abc)` abc is a function.

But in your code, the `__init__` doesn't call the `__init__` of Process class and the object returned is a simple object without a target.
I have added the code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
class multi_subclass(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am multi_subclass")
        super().__init__(target=self.calculate)

    def calculate(self):
        print("Running massive calculations")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.member_variable = "Finished with calculation"


    def calculate2(self):
        print("I also want to be paralellized but NOT together with calculate!")

    def run(self):
        self.calculate()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I am multi_class
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
I am multi_subclass
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Running massive calculations
Your code ran in 1.0859881550000001 seconds instead of 10 seconds because of multiprocessing.LOL
```

Comment: Thank you Gauri, that is exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: @JakeLavender glad I could help. I learned threading and multiprocessing modules recently and this was a good test for me to test my knowledge :P ..thanks